# a more specific term than 'event'?

Tags: word-choice

I have a question about hypernym/hyponym concerning the word (or meaning) of 'event'.

Suppose Glastonbury 2014 is an event. During that Glastonbury 2014 there can be sub-events happening across shorter timespan.  E.g., a gig by someone on day 2; a poor woman fell into toilet on day x; clash between security and a group of people; long waiting queue to get out on the last day...

My question is what's the best choice of terms to describe the two levels of 'event'? I have thought about a few below but I don't know if they are ok or if there are any better ones?

'Glastonbury 2014': **event** 'sub-events mentioned above': **sub-event**

or
'Glastonbury 2014': **macro-event** 'sub-events mentioned above': **micro-event**

or
'Glastonbury 2014': **event** 'sub-events mentioned above': **incident** (doesnt sound right to refer to a gig)

Any suggestions much appreciated!

Comment: Can you work on a case by case basis? That is, "event" describes Glastonbury fine until you need to use the word "event" for something else. At which point, use "festival" for Glasto and "incident" for something potentially negative, "mishap" for accident, "brawl" for a fight and so on. In short, make a list of words you'll need, and then see which ones work best for the individual situation/event.

Comment: @JMB this probably makes the answer to the question. :) +1

Comment: Cheers @MaulikV, but at the time I considered it friendly/useful advice! :)

Comment: "incident (doesnt sound right to refer to a gig)" -- How about this pair: *event* and *activity*?

Comment: Are you looking for a word that *encompasses* both the planned (e.g. performances) and the unplanned/accidental (lady's fall into toilet)? Or two separate words, one for planned, the other for the unplanned?

Comment: @Damkerng 'activity' probably ok to refer to a gig, but then not making sense to refer to that poor woman fell into toilet.

Comment: @TRomano, i would say the first case, i.e., a generic term that can encompass both. I am thinking 'super-event' to describe glastonbury and all those others as 'sub-event' during the super-event. Does that make sense?

Comment: I think the type of the "super-event" changes how you would define the "sub-events". For example, a conference has sessions. A festival has events. A cruise has excursions. [Summer camp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summer_camp) has activities.

Answer (score 1):

Best if you call Glastonbury 2014 by its **proper name: Festival**. Then everything that happens there will be *events*.

So: *Conference, Festival, Meeting, Convention, Championship, Fair* - use the specific word when talking of a specific instance. Only when you need a hypernym for these in bulk, "you specialize in organizing *events*, like..." (and then you're unlikely to conflict with the minor events.)

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I need to describe it in a generic way not any specific kind of events. But you were using 'minor events' which makes more sense. So I can say 'events such as glastonbury, conservatives conference etc' and 'minor events including a gig, group protest etc'

Comment: I'm afraid the super-star of the main concert at the festival may take an offense in having it called a 'minor event' ;)